# Azure Search, filter by Field in array

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to filter a search so that the value of a field is equal to any item in an array.
First I try:

```
"field1 in (12345, 67891) and field2 eq 'xyz'"
```

But it doesn't seem to be supported, so I tried:

```
"search.in(field1, '12345, 67891') and field2 eq 'xyz'"
```

But the following exception is returning:
"No function signature for the function with name 'search.in' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String, Edm.String) search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String). Parameter name: $fi"

Does anyone know the correct way?

btw, the field type is Edm.Int32 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `search.in` function is currently only supported for fields of type `Edm.String`, so it won't work on `Edm.Int32` fields. Feel free to suggest improvements to `search.in` on the Azure Cognitive Search [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) to help the engineering team prioritize.